# Не могу увеличить размер корня в ubuntu 20

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Создал загрузочную флешку с образом ubuntu решил увеличить корневой католог места постоянно нет через утилиту gparted по итогу не получилось
https://i.imgur.com/Nphdy0x.jpeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по картинке у вас нужно сначала подвинуть раздел 6 к конецу диска, освободив дырку между 5 и 6. Тогда можно будет увеличить.

Операция перемещения раздела может занять длительное время.

Изменять размер дисков за счет любого свободного пространства можно только в томах LVM.